# How to best make my catch2 CHECK() output more informative about what it checks?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, usability, catch2

I am working on some code with unit tests using catch2 (and it will stay that way, for reasons).

Now, in the set of unit tests, there are a lot of (pairs of) lines which look like this:

```
  T t1;
  t1 = foo(some, params, here);
  CHECK(my_compare(t1, T{some_literal}));
```

so, `my_out_param` is being set using a single function call, and then it's compared to a T literal.

Now, when this runs and fails, I get:

```
/path/to/test.cpp:493: Failure:
  CHECK(my_compare(t1, T{some_literal}));
with expansion:
  false
```

but obviously I don't get the "some, params, here". Well, I need it. Otherwise, I don't really know which test failed without reading the source code.

Since there's a reliance on macros here, I can't just wrap `CHECK()` in a function and do something fancy inside.

What would you suggest I do to make "some, params, here" get printed alongside "some_literal" when the check fails, while:

1. Keeping my test source code terse.
2. Not repeating myself
3. Still getting a valid file and line number

?

Note: The currently-used version of catch2 is 2.7.0, merged into a single header. If a version change would help, that may be doable.

Comment: I am surprised that support in Catch2 is so limited, boost test has a much better support for it https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/boost_test_universal_macro.html I bookmarked this question.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: 1. It's quite possible that there's some catch2 mechanism for doing what I wanted 2. Actually, I have an inconsistency in my testcase code and the output, let me amend that slightly. It's not a proper equality check.

Comment: `CHECK(my_compare(t1= foo(some, params, here), T{some_literal}));` if you concern is assignation.

Comment: [`CAPTURE`](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/logging.md#quickly-capture-value-of-variables-or-expressions) seems promising too.

Comment: @Jarod42: CAPTURE is not conditional on anything, IIANM. i.e. it will log stuff regardless of whether the check failed or not. But... that gives me an idea.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorry, but that's not true. `CAPTURE` like (`INFO` and `UNSCOPED_INFO`) writes output first to buffer and only outputs that buffer if the next assertion fails (see https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/logging.md#streaming-macros)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CAPTURE` or `INFO` logging macros (see https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/logging.md#streaming-macros).

```
CAPTURE(some);
CAPTURE(params);
CAPTURE(here);
```

or

```
INFO("Params: some="<<some<<", params="<<params<<", here="<<here);
```

should do the trick.

BTW `CAPTURE` only logs variables that were captured in the same section as the failed test. Example:

```
    SECTION("foo"){
        int i = 1;
        CAPTURE(i);
        CHECK(i==1);
    }
    SECTION("bar"){
        int j = 2;
        CAPTURE(j);
        CHECK(j==1);
    }
```

outputs

```
foo.cpp:10: FAILED:
  CHECK( j==1 )
with expansion:
  2 == 1
with message:
  j := 2
```